# How can I make some try method to try downloading files each 20 seconds until the download was successful?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Downloads
{
    class GenerateCountries
    {
        public static List<string> CountriesCodes = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> CountriesNames = new List<string>();

        private string CountriesHtmlAddress;
        private string CountriesHtmlFile;
        private StreamWriter CountriesFile;
        private WebClient Client;

        public void Init()
        {
            CountriesHtmlAddress = "http://sat24.com/en/?ir=true";
            CountriesFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath), "Countries.txt"));
            CountriesHtmlFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath), "Sat24.html");
        }

        public void ExtractCountires()
        {
            Client = new WebClient();
            Client.DownloadFile(CountriesHtmlAddress, CountriesHtmlFile);
            Client.Dispose();

            string tag1 = "<li><a href=\"/en/";
            string tag2 = "</a></li>";

            string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(CountriesHtmlFile);
            s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(tag1));
            s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(tag2) + tag2.ToCharArray().Length);
            s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");

            string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] { tag1, tag2 }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string tag3 = "<li><ahref=\"/en/";

            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 40)
                {
                    break;
                }
                string l = "";
                if (parts[i].Contains(tag3))
                    l = parts[i].Replace(tag3, "");

                string z1 = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf('"'));
                if (z1.Contains("</ul></li><liclass="))
                {
                    z1 = z1.Replace("</ul></li><liclass=", "af");
                }
                CountriesCodes.Add(z1);
                CountriesCodes.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);

                string z2 = parts[i].Substring(parts[i].LastIndexOf('>') + 1);
                if (z2.Contains("&amp;"))
                {
                    z2 = z2.Replace("&amp;", " & ");
                }
                CountriesNames.Add(z2);
                CountriesNames.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < CountriesCodes.Count; i++)
            {
                CountriesFile.WriteLine("Country Code = " + CountriesCodes[i]);
                CountriesFile.WriteLine("Country Name = " + CountriesNames[i]);
            }

            CountriesFile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And in Form1 constructor:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GenerateCountries Countries = new GenerateCountries();
            Countries.Init();
            Countries.ExtractCountires();
        }
```

The problem is in the GenerateCountries class on the line:

```
Client.DownloadFile(CountriesHtmlAddress, CountriesHtmlFile);
```

Sometimes it throw exception on the server side. In many cases it throw the exception/s.

The first exception that sometimes it throw:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send.' IOException: Unable to read data
>   from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host. SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

And this is the second one also sometimes:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

What I want to do is to try and keep downloading each 15 or 20 seconds until the download will be successful.
Try to download if not successful wait 20 seconds then try to download again and so on.

Comment: for retry there are nice library https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: also check this post https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192845/retry-mechanism-for-failed-downloads or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527682/webclient-retry

Comment: Blind retry without understanding the underlying problem is a guaranteed path to an infinite retry loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebClinet`'s Async Methods have events accept a parametr named userToken, which you can set it to the information of the file being downloaded (its download link, its index in the array of files to be downloaded, etc), then when the `DownloadFileCompleted` event triggers, you could checkif it was successful or not and it it has failed you can use this userToken to redownload the file:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if(e.Error!=null)
        ((WebClient)s).DownloadFileAsync(new Uri((string)e.UserState), "C:\\" + ((string)e.UserState).Split('/').Last(), e.UserState)
        //instead of this line you may set a timer that would do the download after sometime
    };

    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/somefile.txt"), "C:\\somefile.txt", "http://example.com/somefile.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Task DownloadContentAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // download content here
}

public async Task RunAsync()
{
  var succeeded = false;
  while(!succeeded)
  {
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    await DownloadContentAsync(cts.Token)
     .ContinueWith((x) => succeeded = x.IsCompleted);
  }
}
```